# Python keeps printing first index of for loop

Tags: python-2.7, file, for-loop, operating-system

I have data in two directories and i'm using `for loop` to read the files from both the folders.

```
path_to_files = '/home/Desktop/computed_2d/'
path_to_files1 = '/home/Desktop/computed_1d/'

for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]:
    df = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

    for filen1 in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files1) if '.ares' in x]:
        df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files1+filen1, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

        print(filen,filen1)
```

Now what's happening is like when tried to print the filenames then it kept printing the names forever. So, its basically taking the first iteration from first loop then print it with all the iteration of the second loop.I don't understand why is it happening.

But what i want to do is, i want to print the first iteration of first `loop` with the first iteration of second `for loop`

As the file names are same in both the folders.So when i do the print, then desired result should look like something like this:

```
(txt_1.txt,txt_1.txt)
(txt_2.txt,txt_2.txt)
(txt_3.txt,txt_3.txt)
(txt_4.txt,txt_4.txt)
```

Where i'm making the mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you seem to want to print pairs of files from `path_to_files` and `path_to_files1`. Since you are nesting a `for loop`, for every iteration of the nested `for loop`, `filen` is not going to change.

I think you might want something more like this:

```
path_to_files = '/home/Desktop/computed_2d/'
path_to_files1 = '/home/Desktop/computed_1d/'

filelistn = [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]
filelist1 = [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files1) if '.ares' in x]

for filen, filen1 in zip(filelistn, filelist1):
    df = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
    df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files1+filen1, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

    print(filen,filen1)
```

For a sample input of:

```
filelistn = ['a.ar', 'b.ar']
filelist1 = ['c.ar', 'd.ar']
```

I get the following output:

```
('a.ar', 'c.ar')
('b.ar', 'd.ar')
```